# how to join 2 separate text to one - selected from string - IN MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, join, substring

I have date in string like "01.02.2012" like "DD.MM.YYYY" and I need it convert to `DATE` or string like "YYYY-MM-DD".

I try:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING( txtdate, 7, 4 ) AS `year` , SUBSTRING( txtdate, 4, 2 ) AS `month` , 
SUBSTRING(txtdate, 1, 2 ) AS `day`
FROM info
```

So I get the year, month and day and now I want to join the texts to one.
I try this just after

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-',year,month,day);
```

but I get an error ..

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to aliased fields elsewhere in a field definition list, unfortunately.

```
SELECT x AS a, CONCAT(y, a)
```

doesn't work. You'd have to use

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', SUBSTRING(txtdate, 7, 4), SUBSTRING(...), SUBSTRING(...))
```

or, if you'd stored that date in a proper DATE field in the database, it'd a simple matter of

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m-%d', datefield)
```